# Detecting mouse event in an image with matplotlib

Tags: image-processing, matplotlib, mouseevent

So I'm trying write a program that detects a mouse click on an image and saves the x,y position. I've been using matplotlib and I have it working with a basic plot, but when I try to use the same code with an image, I get the following error:

> cid = implot.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
>   'AxesImage' object has no attribute 'canvas'

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

im = plt.imread('image.PNG')
implot = plt.imshow(im)

def onclick(event):
    if event.xdata != None and event.ydata != None:
        print(event.xdata, event.ydata)
cid = implot.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

Let me know if you have any ideas on how to fix this or a better way to achieve my goal. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that `implot` is a sub-class of `Artist` which draws to a `canvas` instance, but does not contain a (easy to get to) reference to the canvas.  The attribute you are looking for is an attribute of the `figure` class.

You want to do:

```
ax = plt.gca()
fig = plt.gcf()
implot = ax.imshow(im)

def onclick(event):
    if event.xdata != None and event.ydata != None:
        print(event.xdata, event.ydata)
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes! I couldn't figure out why the plots had canvases and implot didn't. This is perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: @user2227523 If this solved your problem could you accept it (the big gray checkmark on the left)?  It gives both of us rep and marks the question solved for future users.

Comment: @user2227523 No worries. Welcome to SO!

Answer (score 3):

Simply replace `implot.canvas` with `implot.figure.canvas`:

```
cid = implot.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
```